# % not showing in tooltip pie chart highcharts angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, highcharts, pie-chart

[image]    % symbol is not showing in highcharts

```
ageData = {
  chartConfig: {
    options: {

      chart: {
        type: 'pie',
        width: 275,
        height: 220,
        marginTop: 70
      },
      plotOptions: {

        pie: {
          size: 100,
          allowPointSelect: true,
          cursor: 'pointer',
          dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            style: {
              color: '#2A9ACC',
              fontFamily: 'proximanovalight',
              textShadow: 0
            }
          }

        }
      }
    },

    title: {
      text: 'Age',
      style: {
        color: '#2A9ACC',
        font: '16px proximanovalight'
      }
    },

    tooltip: {

      pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>' + this.point.percentage + ' % </b>'
    },
    series: [{
        name: "Age",
        minPointWidth: 20,
        showInLegend: false,
        colorByPoint: true
      }

    ],
    loading: false
  }

}
```

I added the tooltip formatter as specified in some links but no luck. I am not sure about the reason for this issue. Please let me know if you need any more details. Glad to provide. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

According to [`Highcharts Pie` documentation](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/pie-legend), you need to change the line below:

```
pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>' + this.point.percentage + ' % </b>'
```

To something like this:

```
pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
```

Comment: Hi Waldir. Thanks for the prompt response. I tried replacing it as you said. But no luck :( Still % is not showing up...Please find the image I added after replacing the text

Comment: Try to add the `tooltip` configuration section under the `options` section. Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I found the solution for the issue. It seems I have to specify the tooltip inside options part of config as below:

```
                                        chartConfig : {
                                                                    options : {

                                                                        chart : {
                                                                            type : 'pie',
                                                                            width : 275,
                                                                            height : 220,
                                                                            marginTop : 70
                                                                        },

                                                                        tooltip : {
                                                                            pointFormat : '{series.name}: {point.percentage:.1f}%',
                                                                        },
                                                                        plotOptions : {

                                                                            pie : {
                                                                                size : 100,
                                                                                allowPointSelect : true,
                                                                                cursor : 'pointer',
                                                                                dataLabels : {
                                                                                    enabled : true,
                                                                                    style : {
                                                                                        color : '#2A9ACC',
                                                                                        fontFamily : 'proximanovalight',
                                                                                        textShadow : 0
                                                                                    }
                                                                                }

                                                                            }
                                                                        }
                                                                    },

                                                                    title : {
                                                                        text : 'Age',
                                                                        style : {
                                                                            color : '#2A9ACC',
                                                                            font : '16px proximanovalight'
                                                                        }
                                                                    },

                                                                    series : [ {
                                                                        name : "Age",
                                                                        minPointWidth : 20,
                                                                        showInLegend : false,
                                                                        colorByPoint : true
                                                                    }

                                                                    ],
                                                                    loading : false
                                                                }
```

Thanks a lot for your responses. Much appreciated